# Передача Bitmap между процессами?

Tags: c++, gdi, gdi+

У меня есть два процесса Client и Server, один из них генерирует Bitmap мне нужно его передать другому процессу. Я создал между ними FileMapping

Первый процесс Server

```
HANDLE hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(nullptr, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(Preview), "Local\\shared-memory");
if (!hFileMapping) printf("CreateFileMapping: Error %ld\n", GetLastError());

LPVOID lpFileMap = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
if (!lpFileMap) printf("MapViewOfFile: Error %ld\n", GetLastError());
```

Второй процесс Client

```
HANDLE hFileMapping = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, FALSE, "Local\\shared-memory");

LPVOID lpFileMap = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

Во втором процессе (Client) получаю скриншот рабочего стола

```
HDC desktopHdc = GetDC(NULL);
HDC memHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(desktopHdc);
HBITMAP bitmap;

BITMAPINFO bmi;
ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = 800;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = 600;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
char* bmbits;
bitmap = CreateDIBSection(memHdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bmbits, hFileMapping, 0);

//Как мне праивльно записать изображение в секцию здесь?
GetBitmapBits(bitmap, 800 * 600 * 3, bmbits);
```

В первом процессе (Server) пытаюсь его получить но получаю чёрный экран.

```
HDC windowHdc = GetDC(NULL);
HDC memHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(windowHdc);
HBITMAP restore;

BITMAPINFO bmi;
ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = 800;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = 600;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
char* buffer;
HBITMAP bitmap = CreateDIBSection(windowHdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&buffer, hFileMapping, 0);

//Как мне праивльно получить изображение из секции здесь?
SetBitmapBits(bitmap, 800 * 600 * 3, buffer);
```

Comment: Возможно ради передачи куска памяти нет смысла делать MapViewOfFile. Есть же WM_COPYDATA.

Comment: Вместо первого аргумента `CreateCompatibleDC(0)`, а в предпоследний 0

Comment: Напрямую через WM_COPYDATA передать
HBITMAP не получится

Comment: HBITMAP да не получится, это дескриптор уровня процесса, просто когда уже картинка будет в памяти, то проще передать WM_COPYDATA

Comment: ну вот у меня и вопрос как это поместить в память.

Comment: так она вернёт указатель на память с картинкой в bits

Comment: Если hSection - не  ПУСТО (NULL), тогда это должен быть дескриптор объекта "проекция файла в память", созданного при помощи вызова функции CreateFileMapping с флажком PAGE_WRITECOPY или PAGE_READWRITE. Разделы аппаратно-независимого растрового формата (DIB) только для чтения не поддерживаются. Дескрипторы, созданные другим способом становятся причиной  завершения функции CreateDIBSection  ошибкой.

Comment: Дескриптор HBITMAP нельзя передать другому процессу. Чтобы передать все растровые данные, вам нужно независимое от устройства растровое изображение (DIB). Это означает, Bitmap должен быть создан с помощью функции CreateDIBSection. Растровое изображение, зависящее от устройства (DDP), созданное функцией CreateCompatibleBitmap, не может быть сохранено или скопировано в блок памяти.
Преимущество DIB заключается в том, что он обеспечивает прямой доступ к битам растрового изображения (массиву пикселей). Доступ к нему можно получить с помощью GetBitmapBits и SetBitmapBits API. Как то так.

Comment: До передачи растр нормальный или там нули всёже?

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович Покажите как отправку/получение обрабатываете

Comment: Проверил, нули, что то я не так делаю после этого 
bitmap = CreateDIBSection(memHdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&bmbits, hFileMapping, 0);

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович У вас `Get\SetBitampBits` избыточно, после `CreateDIBSection` у вас и память выделена и указатели на нее есть

Comment: @Cerbo что это значит? Я в этом месте и не знаю что делать дальше, я создаю секцию, а как в неё записать изображение я не знаю. И не знаю как его потом достать в другом процессе. Знаю только что я должен создать эти секции в обоих процессах. В одном использовать Сет а в другом Гет. Но как это делается правильно я так и не нашёл ответа. Гуглил долго.

Comment: @Cerbo память выделена но она пустая там одни нули.

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/gdi/capturing-an-image